# Unrecognized function or variable 'options' for simulannealbnd, but works for fminunc on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

When I change the optimization function to simulannealbnd instead of fminunc, MATLAB shows error " No variable named options" and " too many input arguments"
What wrong am i doing?
I changed the code from :

```
if isempty(optimfun)
  % determine whether the MATLAB Optimization toolbox is available and can be used
  if ft_hastoolbox('optim')
    optimfun = @fminunc;
  else
    optimfun = @fminsearch;
  end
end
if isempty(maxiter)
  % set a default for the maximum number of iterations, depends on the optimization function
  if isequal(optimfun, @fminunc)
    maxiter = 1000;
  else
    maxiter = 3000;
  end
end
if isequal(optimfun, @fminunc)
  options = optimset(...
    'TolFun',1e-9,...
    'TypicalX',scale*ones(size(param)),...
    'LargeScale','off',...
    'HessUpdate','bfgs',...
    'MaxIter',maxiter,...
    'MaxFunEvals',2*maxiter*length(param),...
    'Display',display);
elseif isequal(optimfun, @fminsearch)
  options = optimset(...
    'MaxIter',maxiter,...
    'MaxFunEvals',2*maxiter*length(param),...
    'Display',display);
```

to:

```
if isempty(optimfun)
  % determine whether the MATLAB Optimization toolbox is available and can be used
  if ft_hastoolbox('optim')
    optimfun = @simulannealbnd;
  else
    optimfun = @fminsearch;
  end
end
if isempty(maxiter)
  % set a default for the maximum number of iterations, depends on the optimization function
  if isequal(optimfun, @simulannealbnd)
    maxiter = 1000;
  else
    maxiter = 3000;
  end
end
if isequal(optimfun, @simulannealbnd)
    options = optimoptions(...
        'TolFun',1e-9,...
        'TypicalX',scale*ones(size(param)),...
        'MaxIter',maxiter,...
        'MaxFunEvals',2*maxiter*length(param),...
        'Display',display);
end
elseif isequal(optimfun, @fminsearch)
  options = optimset(...
    'MaxIter',maxiter,...
    'MaxFunEvals',2*maxiter*length(param),...
    'Display',display);
% perform the optimization with either the fminsearch or fminunc function
  [param, fval, exitflag, output] = optimfun(@dipfit_error, param, options, dat, sens, headmodel, constr, metric, checkinside, mleweight, reducerank, normalize, normalizeparam, weight, backproject);
```

The  link for code is attached here: [https://github.com/fieldtrip/fieldtrip/blob/master/inverse/ft_inverse_dipolefit.m](https://stackoverflow.com)
I get an error saying  ' Unrecognized function or variable 'options'.' How do i solve this?

Changing optimization function to simulated annealing to converge to global minima for EEG dipole

Comment: **simulannealbnd** requires options structure to be created with **optimoptions** function.